# Is there a search engine for C++ commands?

Tags: c++

I do C++ and R programming since last 3 years.

I wish to know is there a search engine for C++ commands where I can find all the details regarding the command.

This is the example of what I am looking for:
This is a search engine for R commands:
http://www.rseek.org/

Comment: C++ does not have commands, it has functions and classes. Knowing the right terminology will help search for what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google works pretty well.

If you only want C++ hits, use the `site:` restriction, as in ["site:cppreference.com emplace_back"](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=site%3acppreference.com+emplace_back)

Perhaps ["site:cppreference.com pow"](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=site%3acppreference.com+pow) is a better example, since `pow` by itself would normally come up with many unrelated hits.

Of course, keyword search works also, try ["site:cppreference.com natural logarithm"](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=site%3acppreference.com+natural+logarithm)

Answer (score 2):

I use this often: http://www.cplusplus.com/. It has a search box.

Comment: Unfortunately the quality of information on that site is quite low.

Comment: cplusplus.com is known to have various [inaccuracies](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com). I prefer http://cppreference.com

Comment: Thanks for the info guys.. I didn't know it had inaccuracies. I've not come across any, but normally I just do it for looking up APIs of common classes like string